# IIS 7.5 , and out of memory exceptions

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

We recently migrated our 32 bit web application to 2008 Server R2 64 bit on IIS 7.5, with 8GB or RAM

Generally fine: some minor issues, but this afternoon we got a few out of memory exceptions.

I recyled the app pool, which resolved the issue. We didn't see this on IIS 6 / W2k3, so I'm digging around to see if we've lost some configuration.

Given the app is 32 bit, what should I set as the virtual and private memory limits to trigger app pool recycling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a related question here : [64 bit OS / 32 bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153560/64-bit-os-32-bit-process)

It seems the upper limit for the worker process is 2800 mb