# 64 bit OS / 32 bit process

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-x64

What is the maximum private memory that a 32 bit process can address on a 64 bit operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is 2GB. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system) for details

Comment: Thanks - so it seems to me that the w3wp.exe for a 32 bit Asp.Net application should be able to address up to 4GB, since it is LARGEADDRESSAWARE

Comment: The limits are marked differently for .Net - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes.aspx so in this case it will be restricted to 2GB

Comment: Useful article. From my reading of it, I understood 2800 MB is the limit for a 32 bit .Net process in a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yes you are right its 2800 MB

Answer (score 1):

Generally: same as if it was running on a 32bit OS. It's internal pointers are still 32bit, so only 4G addressable. Same limitations apply with kernel reserved address space, which will depend on the exact OS and its configuration (<del>usually the process will have a total of 2 or 3G to play with</del>).

Edit: the above is actually not correct. It appears to be a 2G / 4G option for win64, see the link posted by Neera.